# How to allow client managers to test functions in Youtrack?

Tags: youtrack

I'm trying to set up YouTrack as a bug tracker, but I can't find a way to give my client's managers to open up issues.

Answer (score 0):

For a user to be able to create issues, they need to posses the Create Issue permission. This permission is included in Reporters role. So the easiest solution would be to grant your client's managers the Reporter role in the project.